# How to use json parsing in android

Tags: android, performance

How to parse `JSONObject` from the server. I got the response from the server as

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "authKey": "$2y$13$fg2dFdy7KbSsZP.WIddETOYxOCtJHtFwwGDTJudQ6w7hQcH5vGm16"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is solution

```
try{
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response)
  String status = oject.getString("status")
  String authKey = oject.getString("authKey")
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how can i include my response here...?

Comment: The thing you get this -{
    "status": "success",
    "authKey": "$2y$13$fg2dFdy7KbSsZP.WIddETOYxOCtJHtFwwGDTJudQ6w7hQcH5vGm16"
}---- Is response. Did you understand or not?

Comment: thanks i will check for it

Comment: Your welcome, and don't forget to up-vote for answer if it helps you.

Comment: How it will work if you are getting response in your web view? This authkey will not change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

> A JSON object contains key/value pairs like map. The keys are strings
>   and the values are the JSON types. Keys and values are separated by
>   comma.

You can try with this way

```
             String getStatus = "",authKey="";
            try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject("{"status":"success","authKey":"$2y$13$fg2dFdy7KbSsZP.WIddETOYxOCtJHtFwwGDTJudQ6w7hQcH5vGm16"}"); //Put your Json String  
                getStatus = reader.getString("status");
                authKey = reader.getString("authKey");
                } 
               catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: how do i get the json string into the "Your_Json" place

Comment: @Gopibilla show your work please .

Comment: http://amogaa.com/nimaatri/frontend/web/?r=site/cust-login&username=mohan&password=Test1234

Comment: @Gopibilla check `new JSONObject("{"status":` section

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObj =new JSONObject("your response string");
    String status = jsonObj.optString("status");
    String authKey = jsonObj.optString("authKey");
} catch (JSONException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: how do i place my response string from the web view to code

Comment: Post the code which you tried.

Comment: http://amogaa.com/nimaatri/frontend/web/?r=site/cust-login&username=mohan&password=Test1234 this is the link and i want to get the authkey from this link how can i get it

Comment: Instead of calling from browser why are u not trying by calling **http** request from android ?

Comment: i dont have the detailed knowledge to calling http request and get response from the server if you help me about that please kindly send me some details about the http request and response clearly

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html check this url

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

    String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
    String authKey = jsonObject.optString("authKey");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String status= jsonObject.getString("status");
String authKey = jsonObject.getString("authKey");
```

Comment: what is the response variable here...?

Comment: it's your response string.